# Mockup for sys.stdin?

Tags: python, unit-testing, stdin, mockups

Suppose, you want to write `unittest`s for functions like this one:

```
def test_me(instream):
    out = ""
    for line in instream:
       out += foo(line)
    return out
```

which are normally used like this:

```
test_me(sys.stdin)
```

Now, in your `unittest`s you don't want to use `sys.stdin` but an object that mimics `sys.stdin`'s behaviour and that object should be fully controlled by you. This way you can test the function as it is and you can insert whatever fake-input you like. What kind of object would you need to create to do that?

Comment: check `pexpect` if you want to mock user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `instream` argument is used as a generator; implementing a generator will thus do.  Probably just providing a function with a list of lines will do.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) and/or [`cStringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) modules.